# Comparar uma string em Assembly x86

Tags: assembly

Toda vez que eu digito a letra "F" ou "f" no console, ele sempre vai falar que eu não digitei a letra "f". Por que?

```
section .data:
  msg: db "Digite a letra F: "
  msgLen: equ $- msg

  msgEqual: db "Voce digitou a letra F"
  msgEqualLen: equ $- msgEqual

  msgNotEqual: db "Voce nao digitou a letra F"
  msgNotEqualLen: equ $- msgNotEqual

section .bss
  letra resb 2

section .text:
  global _start

  _start:
    ; Escrever menssagem principal na tela
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, msgLen
    int 0x80
    ; Entrada do teclado
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, letra
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    cmp ecx, "f"
    je .equal
    jne .notEqual

    .equal:
      ; printar a resposta na tela(se for igual)
      mov eax, 4
      mov ebx, 1
      mov ecx, msgEqual
      mov edx, msgEqualLen
      int 0x80
      ; finalizar a aplicação(como se fosse um return)
      mov eax, 1
      mov ebx, 0
      int 0x80

    .notEqual:
      ; printar a resposta na tela(se não for igual)
      mov eax, 4
      mov ebx, 1
      mov ecx, msgNotEqual
      mov edx, msgNotEqualLen
      int 0x80
      ; return
      mov eax, 1
      mov ebx, 0
      int 0x80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na linha:

```
cmp ecx, "f"
```

O programa está comparando o valor armazenado no registrador `ecx` com a letra `f`, porém, após a chamada de sistema [*sys_read*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), esse registrador (ainda) contém o endereço da variável "letra" e não o caractér digitado na entrada pelo usuário.

O valor digitado está armazenado no endereço de memória apontado por "letra", portanto, é necessário indicar que a comparação ocorre entre a letra "f" e o valor armazenado nessa posição da memória ("letra"), e que esse valor tem o tamanho de 1 byte.

Para corrigir o programa, basta trocar a linha acima por:

```
cmp byte [ecx], "f"
```

Outro ponto importante é que o programa compara o código do caractér digitado com o código da letra "f" minúsculo (0x66) e, se a entrada for "F" maiúsculo (0x46), será apresentada a mensagem "Voce nao digitou a letra F".